# async.parallel not executing last cllback function when using with lambda functions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, callback, aws-lambda

I am writing a lambda function in node js. I have main js file (index.js) which based on input event calls a methods in 2nd js file (loader.ls).
The issue is that after the method execution completes in loader.js, the callback in index.js is not getting executed. Below is the code

Code in index.js

```
var yates = require("./yatesLoader");

module.exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    if(event.app === undefined || event.data === undefined){
        context.fail("invalid request");
    }
    if(event.app === 'YatesDataLoader'){
        var result = yates.sendNotification(event.data, function(err, resp){
            if(err){
                console.log("Error : " + JSON.stringify(err));
                context.done(null, "error occured");
            }
            console.log("response : " + JSON.stringify(resp));
            context.done(null, resp);  // SUCCESS with message
        });
    }    
};
```

Code in loader.js

```
var config = require("./config");
var optDynamo = config.DynamoDb;
var optSlack = config.Slack;

var async = require("async");
var req = require("request");
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
  region: optDynamo.region
});

var DynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

var sendNotification = function(data, callback){
    async.parallel([
        sendSlackNotification.bind(null, data, cb),
        saveDataToDynamoDb.bind(null, data, cb)     
    ], function(err, results){
        if (err) {
            console.error("Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            return callback(err, null);
        } else {
            console.log("Success:", JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
            return callback(null, results);
        }
    });
};

var cb = function(err, resp){
    if(err){
        console.log("Error");
    }else {
        console.log("success");
    }   
};

var saveDataToDynamoDb = function(data, cb){
    var params = {
        "TableName" : optDynamo.table,
        "Item" : {
            "TimeStamp" : {"S" : new Date().toString() },
            "ErrorMessage" : {"S" : data }
        }
    };

    console.log("adding new data to DynamoDb");
    DynamoDb.putItem(params, function(err, data){
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            return cb(err, null);
        } else {
            console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            return cb(null, data);
        }
    });
};

var sendSlackNotification = function(data, cb){
    var options = {
        method : 'post',
        body : {"text" : data},
        json : true,
        url :  optSlack.url
    };
    console.log("sending msg to slack");
    req(options, function(err, resp){
        if(err){            
            console.error("Unable to send message to Slack. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            return cb(err, null);
        } else {
            console.log("Message sent to Slack:", JSON.stringify(resp, null, 2));
            return cb(null, resp);
        }
    })
};

module.exports = {sendNotification : sendNotification};
```

Can someone help in understanding what is wrong here.

Comment: Can you share the log output?

Comment: there is no error.. the issue is that the call defined while calling yates.sendNotification in index.js is not getting executed.

Comment: did you try console.logging `event` to make sure you're getting the data that you expect? I don't think its causing you problem but you should return any statements that are considered "final" like `return context.done()`, otherwise it will keep running the statements after it.

Comment: @Ryan - i am getting the data in `event`. the problem here is that after the functions in async.parallel are executed, the final callback is not getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the way you are using `.bind()`. It is changing the arguments that get passed in to `saveDataToDynamoDb()` and `sendSlackNotification()`. So what they see is actually:

```
var saveDataToDynamoDb = function(data, cb, next) { ....
```

where `next` is the callback that the `async` library is expecting you to call. So you could call `next` after `cb`.

```
var saveDataToDynamoDb = function(data, cb, next){
    ...
    DynamoDb.putItem(params, function(err, data){
        if (err) {
            cb(err, null);
            return next(err, null);
        } else {
            cb(err, null);
            return next(null, data);
        }
    });
};
```